# I keep getting .map() is not a function upon first load, but it works when refreshed...any ideas why? MERN stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

So, I have this appointments array coming in from its parent component. This component should map over the array, and then return a div for each item that occurs at a date later than today. Then, when the user clicks the "confirm" button it should re-render the list and remove that item that was just clicked from the list of rendered divs.
The problem is when it re-renders, I get the same "appointments.map() is not a function" error. If I click refresh the component renders as expected with the div that was clicked on removed from the list.
I can't seem to figure out why, as this component shouldn't even load unless the appointments array has a length (as it states in the parent component).

This is the parent component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { getAppointments } from '../../../actions/appointment'
import ConfirmAppointment from '../Appointments/ConfirmAppointment'

const Dashboard = ({user}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        //get appointment data
        dispatch(getAppointments(user?.result._id))
    }, [dispatch])

    const appointments = useSelector((state)=>state?.usersReducer?.appointment)

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <h3>Welcome {user?.result?.firstName}! :D</h3>
                     
                {/* <Link to='/bookappointment'>
                    <button className="ui button" style={{backgroundColor: '#adad85'}}>Book an appointment</button>
                </Link>                   */}
                <Link to="/healthhistory/update" >
                    <button className="ui button" style={{backgroundColor: '#adad85'}}>Update Health History</button>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/dashboard/receipts">
                    <button className="ui button" style={{backgroundColor: '#adad85'}}>View Appointment Receipts</button>
                </Link>
                {appointments?.length === 0 ? (
                    <div>Loading ...</div>
                ) : (
                    <ConfirmAppointment user={user} appointments={appointments} />
                )
                }
            </div>                      
        </>
    )
}

export default Dashboard
```

And this is the component with the .map function:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { confirmAppointment } from '../../../actions/appointment'

const ConfirmAppointment = ({user, appointments}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const { _id } = user?.result

    const today = new Date()
    
    const [reasonForMassage, setReasonForMassage] = useState('')
    const [treatmentConsent, setTreatmentConsent] = useState(false)
    const [glutes, setGlutes] = useState(false)
    const [chest, setChest] = useState(false)
    const [abdomen, setAbdomen] = useState(false)
    const [innerThighs, setInnerThighs] = useState(false)
    const [areasToAvoid, setAreasToAvoid] = useState('')

    const formData = {
        reasonForMassage,
        consents: {
            treatmentConsent,
            glutes,
            chest,
            abdomen,
            innerThighs,
            areasToAvoid
        }
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e, appointmentId) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setTreatmentConsent(true)
        //update appointment with the appointment id
        dispatch(confirmAppointment(_id, appointmentId, formData))
        clear()
    }

    const clear = () => {
        setReasonForMassage('')
        setGlutes(false)
        setChest(false)
        setAbdomen(false)
        setInnerThighs(false)
        setAreasToAvoid(false)
    }

    return (
        appointments?.length === 0 ? (
            <div>
                No upcoming appointments
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div style={{marginTop: '3em'}}>
                <h4>Upcoming Appointments</h4>
                    {appointments && appointments?.map((appointment) => (
                        new Date(appointment?.date) >= today && appointment?.consents?.treatmentConsent !== true ? (                  
                            <div style={{marginBottom: '3em'}} key={appointment._id} >
                                <table className="ui table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>Time</th>
                                            <th>Duration</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{appointment?.date}</td>
                                            <td>{appointment?.time}</td>
                                            <td>{appointment?.duration}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <form className="ui form" onSubmit={(e)=>handleSubmit(e, appointment?._id)} >
                                    <div className="ui fields">
                                        <div className="ui field">
                                            <label>Reason for booking massage:</label>
                                            <input type="text" value={reasonForMassage} onChange={(e)=>setReasonForMassage(e.target.value)}/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="ui field">
                                            <h5>I give consent to massage the following areas:</h5>
                                            <div>
                                                <input type="checkbox" value={glutes} onChange={(e)=>setGlutes(e.target.checked)} />
                                                <label>Glutes</label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" value={abdomen} onChange={(e)=>setAbdomen(e.target.checked)} />
                                                <label>Abdomen</label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" value={chest} onChange={(e)=>setChest(e.target.checked)} />
                                                <label>Chest</label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" value={innerThighs} onChange={(e)=>setInnerThighs(e.target.checked)} />
                                                <label>Inner thighs</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="ui field">
                                            <label>Are there any other areas you would not like to be massaged?</label>
                                            <input type="text" value={areasToAvoid} onChange={(e)=>setAreasToAvoid(e.target.value)} />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" className="ui button">Confirm Appointment</button>
                                </form>                                
                            </div>
                            ) : (                              
                                <div></div>
                            )
                        ))}                 
            </div>
        )
    )
}


export default ConfirmAppointment
```

Comment: I think the error is not because of the map function. On clicking on the button, you appointments are changed to null or undefined. It is no more an array. Thats why the error is comming. Try consoling the appointments

Comment: Also in render part, change the condition appointments?.length === 0 ? to the following

appointments?.length >0 ? <>(data rendering part)</> : <>No upcoming appointments</>

Comment: Actually, this only sort of worked. It did get rid of the "appointments.map() is not a function error," but now when the component re-renders, it doesn't show any divs that should still show up. For example, if I have 2 upcoming appointments, if I click "confirm" for one of the appointments, upon re-render it shows no upcoming appointments when it should still show the other appointment. If I refresh the page, it will show the second appointment that should still be there. Any thoughts on how to get it to show up without refreshing?

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to get the useEffect to activate once I press "confirm"? Do you think that would load the missing divs when the component re-renders?